# Why does React code work without any errors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I have some question.

I had started React tutorial [this page](https://www.taniarascia.com/getting-started-with-react/). And I created React project by using 'create-react-app' and delete some files (/src/App.js .. etc.). Finally I written code below and running code.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
       <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8" />
          <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
          <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
          <meta
             name="description"
             content="Web site created using create-react-app"
          />
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
          <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
          <title>React App</title>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div id="root"></div>
       </body>
    </html>
```

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
       return(
          <div className="App">
             <h1>Hello, React!</h1>
             <h2>Created react-tutorial</h2>
          </div>
       )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

So, I don't know why no error in running this project. I looked at the 'index.html', but there was no script link tag. Why have no errors? Because I used 'create-react-app'?

PS. Some contexts may be strange because I used some Google translate service. Sorry :(..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `create-react-app` to bootstrap your project then you need to be aware that `create-react-app` has a couple of things abstracted, which makes it easy to create a react app without having to bother about scripts, configuration and build tools.

From the [Docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/folder-structure), it was stated that for the project to build, these files must exist with exact filenames:

`public/index.html` is the page template;

`src/index.js` is the JavaScript entry point.

Here's a link to the [Getting Started](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started) guide, I hope this helps. Good luck!

*P.S From your code - `index.js`, I can see you still have a reference to `index.css`, just wanted to point this out since you said you deleted everything. You might also want to take out the two `<link>` tags in the index.html file which is referencing an image and the manifest.json file from the `public` folder (if they don't exist anymore)*

Comment: Thanks your advice. Now I did understand why run without any errors. It's very useful information. :D